# Google Analytics Setting Up A PageView On Hash Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, jquery-isotope, pageviews

I'm trying to get a home page that has a bunch of content under [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

to show each hash change as a pageview in Google Analytics. Originally, I was going to do this as events, but it really should be pageviews.

So I setup the modified GA:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', {'allowAnchor': true});
ga('send', 'pageview', { 'page': location.pathname + location.search + location.hash});
```

In Google Analytics, I see the hash tag now if someone goes to a specific URL — example: http://www.example.com/#pet-health 
If they reload the page, I see that hash in GA, but not if they click on an Isotope "nav" link to get to it. If they click, I'm just seeing "/"

In the Isotope firing, what I have doesn't seem to be working:

```
//Sets up filtering on click of Isotope navigational elements 
    $('#isotopeFilters a, .subnav a, #isotopeContainer .isotopeNav a, .page-template-page-home-php #logo').click(function(){
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        var prettyselector = selector.substr(1);
        ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname+location.search+location.hash);

        location.hash = prettyselector;

        $('#isotopeFilters a, .subnav a').removeClass('active');
        $('a[class="' + prettyselector + '"]').addClass('active');

        $container.isotope({ 
            filter: selector,
            itemSelector: '.item',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: 270
            },
            animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false,
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

I thought that this line in the click function would do the trick:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname+location.search+location.hash);
```

Is my syntax incorrect or missing something?

```
//Fires Isotope functionality when hash/URL changes
    $(window).hashchange( function(){
        if(location.hash!=''){
            var hashfilter = '.' + location.hash.substr(1);
        }else{
            var hashfilter = '.home';
        }

        $container.isotope({
            filter: hashfilter,
            itemSelector: '.item',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: 270
            },
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false,
           }
        });
        isotopeSubNav();
    });

    if(location.hash!=''){
        var hashfilter = '.' + location.hash.substr(1);
        ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname+location.search+location.hash);
        $(hashfilter).addClass('active');
    }
```

That's using the same syntax, so I'm assuming if I fix one, copying the syntax to the hashchange function will get that recording as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To change the page path that gets sent to GA, you would to just make a slight modification to your code:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': location.pathname+location.search+location.hash});
```

More information can be found here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced?hl=en#fieldObject

Comment: Thanks this works, but consider updating the code, as it's missing the closing curly bracket `}` and that gives syntax error. It should look like this:

`ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': location.pathname + location.search + location.hash});`

Comment: Thanks, fixed the bug!

Answer (score 7):

Sending `page` in sending `pageview` call is not recommended by Google:

> While technically the send command for pageview hits accepts an
>   optional page field as the third parameter, passing the page field
>   that way is not recommend when tracking single page applications. This
>   is because fields passed via the send command are not set on the
>   tracker—they apply to the current hit only. Not updating the tracker
>   will cause problems if your application sends any non-pageview hits
>   (e.g. events or social interactions), as those hits will be associated
>   with whatever page value the tracker had when it was created.

Use:

```
ga('set', 'page', location.pathname+location.search+location.hash);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

[Google Analytics guide on tracking Single Page Applications.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full code sample to track hash pageviews and changes in google analtyics:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
    ga('set', 'page', location.pathname+location.search+location.hash);
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", function (event) {
        ga('set', 'page', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash);
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently Google Analytics configuration loads Google Tag Manager script and is using ***gtag*** function and not ***ga*** so for me, previous solutions throws errors because *'ga is not defined'*.  What i do is a modification of inital Google Analytics configuration script with:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=YOUR-GA-ID"></script>
<script>
     window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
     function gtag() {
         dataLayer.push(arguments);
     }
     gtag('js', new Date());
     gtag('config', 'YOUR-GA-ID', {
         'page_path': location.pathname + location.hash
     });
 </script>
```

To send content changes when page does not reload or URL (and/or content) change without reloading javascript, you must include somewhere in your scripts this code:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function (event) {
       gtag('event', 'pageview', {
         'page_path': location.pathname+location.search+location.hash
       });
});
```

You can take a look at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data

And at https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/event

Comment: I used your code with gtag. In Real-Time GA, I see urls with hash, but in Behavior->Site Content I see only one url: "/" without hash. How to fix it to see pages with hash in Behavior->Site Content?

Comment: I see hastag urls under Behavior->Site Content... i dont have this problem